# Function of Statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. random variables from a random sample of size $n$.

Find $f(x)$ such that

$$f(\bar X)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$$

The second term is obvious (in other words, $f(x)=\text{???}+x$), but what function can I possibly define that will give me the first term?  I don't see how I can decompose X bar like that in order to sum the squares.  This has me very confused.

Comment: I am confused too. This is impossible. Let $f$ be some function. Then there are many possibilities for the $X_i$ that would yield $\sum_i X_i=0,$ all of which must result in the same value for the LHS, but generally different values for the RHS.

Comment: Perhaps this is an awkward way of drawing attention to the formula $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac 1 n (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2].$